# How to shrink flexbox when downsizing image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to center items on a page and also to center items within a row. I have to handle potentially large images within the row, so I am using max-width=40% to downsize the image. However, when I do this the flexbox for the applicable row does not shrink to fit the new image size, but retains the size as if the image is still max-width=100%. How can I make the flexbox row smaller to account for the 40% max width property?

Here current html code:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;">
    <label>This is my header.</label>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center; border: 1px solid black;">
        <img style="max-width: 40%; padding: 5%;" src="path_to_my_image" alt="(!)"/>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black">
            <label>Here is my label</label><br>
            <label>Here is another label</label>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is an image of what the current display looks like with a border around the flexbox row:
[image: Image with max-width=40%]

Here is what it looks like without setting max-width (bottom cropped to fit):
[image: max-width property not set]

Comment: Hi John, I don't see the issue: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-dawn-cz23i?file=/index.html).

Comment: @mtl you need to use a larger image to see the problem. With the link you provided it will not show the problem since the image is small. I made a new example with a large image. Change max-width or remove it to see the problem more: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-night-5b6pi?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why `<img>` are not easy to work with as a child of a flexbox element. It does not respond to `flex-basis` from my experience.

But as a workaround, you can wrap the `<img>` with a `<div>` like this, and set the `<div>`s initial height to 40% of the container:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;">
    <label>This is my header.</label>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center; border: 1px solid black;">
        <div style="flex: 0 1 40%; padding: 5%;">
          <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-d68l8RLoLc4/UWAJF-ofbJI/AAAAAAAAST4/SUJbO2Dz-RI/s1600/cat1.jpg" alt="(!)"/>
        </div>     
        <div style="border: 1px solid black">
            <label>Here is my label</label><br>
            <label>Here is another label</label>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used ["flex" shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) above to set the `flex-grow` property of the image container `div` to 0 so that the browser does not adjust the size of the image container if there are extra space on the flexbox container.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS object-fit Property to solve this thing.
refer w3school CSS object-fit Property for more help.

Comment: You could add a link to the W3school doc ?